# Why do I not need to explicitly lend a borrowed, mutable variable?

Tags: recursion, rust, ownership

I've just written a small Rust program which calculates Fibonacci numbers and memoizes the calculation. It works, but I'm a little confused about why, especially the recursive call. (It also probably isn't idiomatic.)

Here's the program:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let n = 42; // hardcoded for simplicity
    let mut cache = HashMap::new();
    let answer = fib(n, &mut cache);
    println!("fib of {} is {}", n, answer);
}

fn fib(n: i32, cache: &mut HashMap<i32,i32>) -> i32 {
    if cache.contains_key(&n) {
        return cache[&n];
    } else {
        if n < 1 { panic!("must be >= 1") }

        let answer = if n == 1 {
            0
        } else if n == 2 {
            1
        } else {
            fib(n - 1, cache) + fib(n - 2, cache)
        };
        cache.insert(n, answer);
        answer
    }
}
```

Here's how I understand what's going on:

- In `main`, `let mut cache` means "I want to be able to mutate this hashmap (or re-assign the variable)".
- When `main` calls `fib`, it passes `&mut cache` to say "I'm lending you this, and you're allowed to mutate it."
- In the signature of `fib`, `cache: &mut Hashmap` means "I expect to be lent a mutable HashMap - to borrow it with permission to mutate"

(Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

But when `fib` recurses, calling `fib(n -1, cache)`, I do not need to use `fib(n -1, &mut cache)`, and I get an error if I do: "cannot borrow immutable local variable `cache` as mutable". Huh? It's not an immutable local variable, it's a mutable borrow - right?

If I try `fib(n - 1, &cache)`, I get a slightly different error:

```
error: mismatched types:
expected `&mut std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<i32, i32>`,
   found `&&mut std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<i32, i32>`
```

Which looks like it's saying "I expected a mutable reference and got a reference to a mutable reference".

I know that `fib` is lending in the recursive call because if it gave up ownership, it couldn't call `cache.insert` afterwards. And I know that this isn't a special case for recursion, because if I define `fib2` to be nearly identical to `fib`, I can have them recurse via each other and it works fine.

**Why do I not need to explicitly lend a borrowed, mutable variable**?

Comment: You could pass ownership, and have the function return a tuple with the answer and the cache: [PlayPen](http://is.gd/tUadZ0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your three points are pretty much spot-on. When the compiler won't allow you to pass `&mut cache`, it is because the value is actually already borrowed. The type of `cache` is `&mut HashMap<i32, i32>`, so passing `&mut cache` results in a value of type `&mut &mut HashMap<i32, i32>`. Just passing `cache` results in the expected type.

The specific error message `cannot borrow immutable local variable cache as mutable` is triggered because the variable `cache` isn't itself mutable, even though the memory it points to (the `HashMap`) is. This is because the argument declaration `cache: &mut HashMap<i32, i32>` doesn't declare a `mut` variable. This is similar to how a `let` differs in mutability from a `let mut`. Rust does support mutable arguments, which in this case would look like `mut cache: &mut HashMap<i32, i32>`.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know I could have a mutable value in an immutable variable. Are you sure? `let mut cache = ` makes both mutable - is there a way to declare just the structure mutable? Also, if I add `cache = &mut HashMap::new();` to the top of `fib`, I get a lifetime error, but not a "you can't re-assign this variable" error.

Comment: Also: interesting that "this is a mutable borrow" is checked via a type. Thanks for helping me understand. :)

Comment: @NathanLong You can indeed have a mutable reference in an immutable variable. This is because Rust just needs the mutable reference to be unique: no other piece of code may be able to read or modify the value. It is part of the borrow checker of the compiler to make sure, that all `&mut` are guaranteed to be unique (the same isn't required for `&`). Since variables are always unique (since you own them), an immutable `&mut` reference is still unique, and it can therefore be modified. You may want to check out [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html) too. :)

Comment: Ah, right, of course. `main` could have a hash that *it* intends to mutate, but lend it to `print` immutably - "I'm just giving you permission to read this, not modify it".

Answer (score 0):

In your function, `cache` is a **reference** of the outside `HashMap`. And if you still write `& mut cache`, **you are trying to mutate a reference**, not the original `HashMap`.