# Rust cannot borrow immutable local variable as mutable. However, it is defined as mutable

Tags: rust

I'm using xml-rs to read an xml output from [tiled](http://mapeditor.org) which is a 2d level/tile map editor for games.

I have my parse method, where it all starts:

```
pub fn parse(path: String) {
    let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let file = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut parser = EventReader::new(file);
    let mut tilesets: Vec<TileSet> = vec![];

    let mut tag_attributes: Vec<OwnedAttribute> = make_attributes();
    let mut tag_name = String::from_str("");

    {
        let event = parser.next();
        match event {
            XmlEvent::StartElement { name, attributes, .. } => {
                tag_name = name.local_name;
                tag_attributes = attributes;
            }
            XmlEvent::EndElement {name, .. } => {
            }
            XmlEvent::Error(e) => {
                println!("Error: {}", e);
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    if tag_name == "tileset" {
        let tileset = next_tileset(&mut parser, &tag_attributes);
        tilesets.push(tileset);
    }

    for tileset in tilesets {
        println!("{}", tileset);
    }
}
```

The parser variable is created as mutable, and passes to next_tileset. No complaints yet. Where it falls apart is in the next_tileset method:

```
fn next_tileset(parser: &mut EventReader<BufReader<File>>, attributes: &Vec<OwnedAttribute>) -> TileSet {
    let mut tileset = TileSet{ name: "".to_string(), imagesource: "".to_string(), imageheight: 0, imagewidth: 0, margin: 0, spacing: 0, tilewidth: 0, tileheight: 0, tiles: vec![] };
    for attribute in attributes {
        match attribute.name.local_name.as_ref() {
            "name" => { tileset.name = attribute.value; },
            "margin" => { tileset.margin = attribute_as_usize(&attribute.value); },
            "spacing" => { tileset.spacing = attribute_as_usize(&attribute.value); },
            "tilewidth" => { tileset.tilewidth = attribute_as_usize(&attribute.value); },
            "tileheight" => { tileset.tileheight = attribute_as_usize(&attribute.value); },
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    loop {

        let mut tag_name = String::from_str("");
        let mut tag_type: Tag;
        let mut tag_attributes: Vec<OwnedAttribute> = Vec::<OwnedAttribute>::new();

        {
            let event = parser.next();
            match event {
                XmlEvent::StartElement { name, attributes, .. } => {
                    tag_type = Tag::Open;
                    tag_name = name.local_name;
                    tag_attributes = attributes;
                },
                XmlEvent::EndElement { name, .. } => {
                    tag_type = Tag::Close;
                    tag_name = name.local_name;
                },
                _ => {
                    tag_type = Tag::Neither;
                }
            }
        }
        match tag_type {
            Tag::Open => {
                if tag_name == "image" {
                    parse_image(&mut tileset, &tag_attributes);
                }
                else if tag_name == "tile" {
                    let tile = next_tile(&mut parser, &tag_attributes);
                    tileset.tiles.push(tile);
                }
            },
            Tag::Close => {
                if tag_name == "tileset" {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
            },
            Tag::Neither => {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }


    return tileset;
}
```

You'll see the match inside the loop, it passes a mutable reference of the parser to `next_tile`. So this is where it gives the error. Wondering if it has to do with the fact it's using a BufReader.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why do I not need to explicitly lend a borrowed, mutable variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418966/why-do-i-not-need-to-explicitly-lend-a-borrowed-mutable-variable)

Comment: @DK it does actually :). Since one cannot pass a mutable variable as immutable, makes sense to omit the &mut bit after the fact. Just didn't think about it as such.